# Windows bit torrent client with blacklist support?

Tags: bittorrent

Are their any Windows bit torrent clients that support IP blacklisting, much like Transmission does under Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) contains the facility to load an ipfilter.dat file.  I haven't implemented this myself, but a quick Google for "[utorrent ipfilter](http://www.google.com/search?q=utorrent+ipfilter)" yields much information.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea uTorrent supported this feature. Let me give it a try.

Comment: These two articles where helpful, http://www.davidmoore.info/2009/05/27/set-up-ip-filtering-in-utorrent-and-keep-your-ipfilterdat-up-to-date-easily/ and http://www.zeropaid.com/news/6443/ip_filtering_with_utorrent/.

Answer (score 1):

qBittorrent also has this feature. I run a scheduled task weekly to download and move ipfilter.dat to my qBittorrent folder, and it works.